# How to remove the actions in a Sonata admin class?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am working with a Symfony 2.7 app that uses the Sonata admin bundle.

In an admin class I've built, the following code is present inside the `configureListFields` method:

```
        ->add('_action', 'actions', [
            'actions' => [
                'show' => ['sort'=>''],
                'edit' => ['sort'=>''],
                'delete' => ['sort'=>''],
            ]
        ])
```

But I don't want all those actions to be present. So I make it look like this instead:

```
        ->add('_action', 'actions', [
            'actions' => [
                'edit' => ['sort'=>''],
            ]
        ])
```

... and I find that, surprisingly, nothing changes in the list view. All three actions are still present. I have also tried removing the "actions" key entirely. Neither approach seems to work.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I remove actions that I don't want?

Answer (score 2):

Add a function configureRoutes in your admin class

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $collection->remove('edit')
    // or if you want to remove everything except some routes
    $collection->clearExcept(array('list', 'show'));
}
```

Comment: This feels like it should work, but sadly, it did not. Maybe it's something that works on a different version of the frramework -- mine is quite old.

Comment: which version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.7

Comment: witch sonata version ?

Comment: Here's partial output of `composer show`: 

sonata-project/admin-bundle              2.3.7 
sonata-project/core-bundle               2.3.9

Comment: See https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/2.3.7/Admin/Admin.php
getRouteCollection exists. There should be something on your code that I can't guess. I think that it is not sonata related